# Vega Lite - Filter out bar chart values by interacting with legend

Tags: javascript, html, vega-lite, vega

I’m currently building a Vega-Lite chart and one requirement is that it needs to be interactive with the legend as you can see in the images below:

[Vega lite bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXLfK.png) |
[Vega lite bar chart filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHRug.png)

The idea is that when I click on a legend item, the values matching in every bar should be filtered out (disappear) instead of being highlighted. I think it should be pretty straightforward but I doubt if it's possible.

Here's the prototype I'm currently building in [Vega-Lite Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDsABh1L4NMljQAmPUrVJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtUFcxw0Ic6dN+HUCdAA5FEAgbTAZXdABhAEEABQAVAFUAJQBRAAIAMUSASQAZbIARCKQENgZZTDQdAF8FT2sfdH8QkPClKOtY3wA1AHki8oqqmrqG1GbWkC8Ov2DuoN7I6MH0ZOLKpWra+u0Wtu9fLqCeiP6YuJAktKy8+JGAOXyizIBZSYPp46oUynRbtC6rK7rG5be67TKpXKPDI5RHvT4-P4gQ4zNAAZhBS3BAUhYWhA3uSOeuRyAEV0tkAMqpTHYwEAFgJYM6EOCUL6MN8cIRlJRtPpTJZANmHIWhO5xN5pP55N8iXSqQAEiNMkUAFqSo6zeZnZaXRUATjJd18IryhVKBpxc0553lax0luV1vQo3GjvZLtNPJCns2Kp2eymhrQADZA0T3aHbtsHilkS80V9fvssVK0ABGeNuklJgUR+GItNU14fLP+2Zx2VclYKkNWlO26nZOmM5k51mzMRFluJ9uwxIVzti3v1tAyk0Jktj1XqrU6-X9vPOpuukeQ-M6ZcJKso+1lTfR7cL4u8g9HkC+iYXp3z0G7s2BO9elO7cZRp1DjuQatvwX5ht6qZPCiNbotm-4BkBi63oe37jpOJ4ZrWGLPoCgHXnuyH3lO3bin28HSsOH6gSh4E-hOwoYV2PYSjhDaUcG1H3mqmranqs6oPiiE3p++ZEYxZ78cab7AWs+aiahwxjE+5GNOxIFyfev6sXOamyfJtEUoxMF1tpqAHrp+76cmaEMVBmGwfxgn4VRGkKcedlMaR-FaBZt5WWWIBCpWHnTixKmoKEvkiVxq68Ru4V4dJSGfqYYkeRJplSXKBEpfej78YWQk5aBqVuYFkb-JeTlJcJJVpemqJYXBlVOoVzkcfmpUGYK9HBQ1xnYeF1XZS5XXWTajGhWRLWAo27XqWNAVBcRzHTbml5zTVxWdTFPHrvxwJFS5uL1VSGXhVlzbHXlSmOVFoEnWVWnhYd82yY93Xuf1maDTNbFHR1H3jeWtnfU1d0A+pQMBStXmmZtI2A5pvWwzOpnDVdSNldxa58ej935myp2nsU55DQTRNlflmUU8jf5-QWtNlZ2A3NetrWXe+HWU595XoR5rMFUzvOo2FDOoD5kOyTzwN86DVJTfxCOY+pMsBTjcX8UOAC6LQgMgABOADWvhMEgBsRDg5vVHEHggLI1TLNZAD6gjkHAshqDccBu1AsygJgACeODLDgbA0McSgAGY0D7ai291utKHIvhQMIUAm0oTAR176Bu2QHte002tKJgBtILIEBR2wBsIO4oAx4I3gW3YIBW+XdfoC7+eFyATQglAjhQAwgjNjQUcABReAwCCUNZuQALxL7kADkGv7eUK8KLk+i5OPU8DLP89Lwvq-LZNJFo1vuT5tv+-T0fMKL8vK+i321+mHfk8P3PT8n2fKMjI-WzNfXEX8D4xEfuSZ+p9X5APBpvbebJwE-2Pi-LS18xAoMPr-aB-8V7U2vjGbBkDcF3BgavTsGVr5aG3qEAAlIwphjCqj3GsiMA2ag4AW2LkoD2UA2BqAjmQNAoAAAeoiQCYBoAgOA6RZB0F8IHOA5saj1BgISaOsdBC5ySqXYOywa5CIdoIKoYiaBxE8GwZAEc0BR0cBAOAShR5MB9tkMROAW4gDcNI2R+Qa7IEwBAmelAHBOCcavAApGoFe9Dt6+LgP42u1hgmzzCc4beK9omxOfqvHQ+YV65AAD5FNyD-HOcAxG5JXjoQpAB+XIPiZGJICSkn+6SIlZKYLE+JzSkmBNSaExwGTV65EiYHWJ2tcioFXoU7WERq7JNmCASJABNCI0iM4MhoAALw6M0PWgdJExzjr4AcGyDG+AAI4MArtI6INBSBmIsZIsgBt1BoDLs4fuSgBGCBrsc7Rujxr6JDr4WQ1iI6OBuIPN2kiuCIGWIPbwZAa6B3MEwCIahrFIFsagNwkEGrnSUNTCIz0lAs2AZic+AsqU5jftSwBIVL5ixAOvPGIBdZ6yMdwwFpyu4wg4VwnhycrZQDoEc1uAjPZ0HYPIVu7dqi+G7u7T2EQOmMyUBquYlBgT9yAA)

I'm currently using `params` for creating a binding with the legend and then `transform > filter`, but the result is that when I click, all the legend items are filtered out except the selected one.

Any idea or suggestion is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with the legend, but how about a second chart with hconcat? Use Shift+Click to select multiple items from the second chart that acts as a legend.

[image: Sample]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 700,
  "height": 200,
  "title": {
    "text": "Chart Title",
    "anchor": "middle",
    "fontSize": 14
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "PAID", "amount": 7},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 2},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-08", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "PAID", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 1},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 5},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-09", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "PAID", "amount": 5},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 5},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-10", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "PAID", "amount": 4},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 10},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 7},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 8},
      {"date": "2022-02-11", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 5},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 1},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "PAID", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 1},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-12", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 2},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "PAID", "amount": 2},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-13", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "CAPTURE FAILED", "amount": 3},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "VOIDED", "amount": 0},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "PAID", "amount": 1},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 10},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED", "amount": 1},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 7},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED", "amount": 6},
      {"date": "2022-02-14", "status": "AUTHORIZED", "amount": 5}
    ]
  },
  "hconcat": [
    { "mark": "bar",
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"param": "pts"}},
        {
          "calculate": "if(datum.status === 'AUTHORIZED', 0, if(datum.status === 'PART CAPTURE REQUESTED', 1, if(datum.status === 'CAPTURE REQUESTED', 2, if(datum.status === 'PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED', 3, if(datum.status === 'CAPTURE CONFIRMED', 4, if(datum.status === 'PAID', 5, if(datum.status === 'VOIDED', 6, if(datum.status === 'CAPTURE FAILED', 7, 8))))))))",
          "as": "statusOrder"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate",
          "field": "date",
          "title": "date",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "axis": {
            "domain": false,
            "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%d'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%d') == '01' || datum.index == '0' ? [timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, ' %y')] : '' ]",
            "format": "%Y",
            "tickSize": 0
          }
        },
        "y": {"field": "amount", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {"grid": true}},
        "color": {
          "field": "status",
          "type": "nominal",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "category20b",
            "domain": [
              "CAPTURE FAILED",
              "VOIDED",
              "PAID",
              "CAPTURE CONFIRMED",
              "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED",
              "CAPTURE REQUESTED",
              "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED",
              "AUTHORIZED"
            ]
          }
        },
        "order": {"field": "statusOrder"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"param": "pts", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.2
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "params": [{
        "name": "pts",
        "select": {"type": "point", "encodings": ["y"]}
      }],
      "mark": {"type": "bar"},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "type": "ordinal", 
          "field": "status",
          "title": "status",
          "scale": {
            "scheme": "category20b",
            "domain": [
              "CAPTURE FAILED",
              "VOIDED",
              "PAID",
              "CAPTURE CONFIRMED",
              "PART CAPTURE CONFIRMED",
              "CAPTURE REQUESTED",
              "PART CAPTURE REQUESTED",
              "AUTHORIZED"
            ]
          }
        },
        "color": {"field": "status","type": "nominal"},
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"param": "pts", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.02
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "legend": {"disable": true},
    "axisYBand": {"titleAngle": 0, "titleX": -50, "titleY": -10, "titleAlign": "left"}

  }
}
```